# Jquery won't influence dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, dynamic

I'm making a form that is dynamically loaded into the content area. A part ofd that form should be replicated by jQuery when clicking a link, to add more participants. Trouble is, it won't respond. I've searched around on here and google, but for some reason the answers given there don't work.

Here is the html (or at least the part of it that matters):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <div> 
                <h1>Hello, I am a form!</h1>
                <form id="contactform">
                    <p class="respondent">
                        <input type="text" value "first name" />
                        <input type="text" value="last name" />
                    </p>
                    <span id="addRespondent">add respondent</span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the form is dynamically loaded into the div contained in the "content" div with a .load() function, from an external html file. It replaces other content earlier present in that div.

I tried something like this with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (e){
    $('#main').on('click','#addRespondent', function(e) {
        $('p.respondent').clone().prependTo('#addRespondent');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This is not a problem with incorrectly using the .clone() or .prependTo() functions, even when I put a simple alert into the function, nothing happens. I've tried fiddling with find and filter, without result. I'd appreciate it if someone would point out what I did wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you're adding the `.on()` here to `#addRespondent` right? But not `#main` which is also dynamically loaded. Just a guess, but what happens if you change your second line to: `$('body').on('click','#addRespondent', function(e) { ...` and throw an alert immediately after it.

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/esXDQ/ do you have any other code that could interfere ? perhaps multiple DOM elements with the same ID ?

Comment: Any chance you have multiple elements with the same id `addRespondent`?

Comment: $('p.respondent').first().clone()

Comment: Your console shows anything?

Comment: `value "first name"` is a typo? There should be an `=`

Comment: Why does the `ready` callback declare an `e` argument? It's not used, and it's not an event.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to `insertBefore`, rather than `prependTo`?

Comment: I can see no reason why this wouldn't work. We can't replicate your issue - I'm closing as too localised.

Comment: @ManseUK: true, when I insert flat code into it, it works. trouble is, the form is dynamically loaded with .load(), which is probably somehow preventing the event from bubbling up to #main.

Jimbo: #main is static, only code within '#content div' is dynamic.

Console shows nothing by the way, as if nothing is happening at all.

Comment: Is there a chance that `#main` itself is loaded dynamically?

Comment: @1llegible try delegating to `document` anyways

Comment: Tried that, also tried delegating it to body, #main (as shown) and #content, without success. Sadly, no success

Comment: @1llegible Any exception by some previous code? Have you checked the console?

Comment: @JanDvorak No exceptions from previous code, just a few type, syntax and reference errors in jquery.min.js that Firebug keeps whining about (jquery file is hosted by google). Also some of the same in the Cufon script, but the situation is the same when I remove Cufon altogether.

Comment: @1llegible are you using the public beta? If so, you should downgrade to the latest stable (1.9)

Comment: @JanDvorak. No, I'm using 1.8.2.

Comment: @1llegible anyways, reference errors in jQuery are not a good thing. Test in the console if jQuery works at all. Chances are it's not and you need to change your CDN.

Comment: jQuery does work, any code influencing stuff out of the dynamically loaded div works as expected. I tried linking to Microsoft's CDN and hosting the js file on the server, with the same results.

Comment: Can you link me to your site?

Answer (score 0):

the only issue I can see in your code is that instead of

```
$('p.respondent').clone().prependTo('#addRespondent');
```

(add every `p.respondent` to the start of `#addRespondent`), you probably want

```
$('p.respondent:first').clone().insertBefore('#addRespondent');
```

(add the first `p.respondent` just before `#addRespondent`). Perhaps you want to clean the form as well?

```
$('p.respondent:first')
  .clone().insertBefore('#addRespondent')
  .find("input").val("");
```

---

Also, is there a chance that `#main` doesn't exist on document ready? If so, instead of

```
$('#main').on('click', ...
```

you should delegate to some other element:

```
$(document).on('click', ...
```